# Clustered Stacked bar plot over time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart

I have a data frame as below:

```
   time       type      category   count
2021/01/01   regular       A         2
2021/01/02   new           B         3
2021/01/02   regular       A         5
2021/01/03   new           A         1
... and so on
```

What I want is a clustered stacked bar plot such that the time is on the x-axis and is in order, the count on the y-axis, and the plot should be able to tell the information like on a particular day how many regular types of category A visited (count) out of how many total regulars that day and same for the new type.

I am assuming for this we first need to convert the data in a way so that we have all the combinations with zero counts as well so like the first entry in the above table will be converted into four entries like:

```
   time       type      category   count
2021/01/01   regular       A         2
2021/01/01   regular       B         0
2021/01/01   new           A         0
2021/01/01   new           B         0
... and so on
```

Kindly guide me on how I can achieve what I want. I am new to this visualization stuff

**Edit**
I am able to fill in missing values using:

```
pd.DataFrame({'count' :df.groupby(['time','type','category']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()}).reset_index()
```

Still not sure regarding how to plot this in a stacked multi bar plot. If there is a better option than this plot, Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What you expect is not fully clear (please provide an example, even just a schematic), but here are some examples.

First, you need to rework a bit you dataframe using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='time', columns=['type', 'category']).fillna(0)['count']
df_pivot
```

output:

```
type       regular  new     
category         A    B    A
time                        
2021/01/01     2.0  0.0  0.0
2021/01/02     5.0  3.0  0.0
2021/01/03     0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Then you can plot with:

```
df_pivot.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked bars]

If you want to make sure that you have all categories, you need to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
import itertools
idx = itertools.product(df['type'].unique(), df['category'].unique())
df_pivot = df_pivot.reindex(idx, axis=1).fillna(0)
df_pivot.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked plot with all combinations]